# Urllib in python 3

Tags: python

Hey guys so what i am trying to do is pretty simple, i just want to get the source code of a website and check if a text is present within it. Here what i have have done so far:

```
link = urllib.request.urlopen("http://someurl.com")
x = link.read()

if "prefix" in x:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

I get the website code, and i can print it and all is nice however when i am trying to check if a "prefix" text exist inside the source code i get an error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: It returns a byte string, which you'll need to decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib.read()` returns the content as a byte string. You'll need to decode this byte string to parse its contents:

```
x_decoded = str(x, 'latin-1')
```

Alternatively, if you don't wish to decode, you may convert your search string to a byte string by prepending `b` to the literal:

```
if b"prefix" in x:
   ...
```

This works too.